# 500 Internal Server Error when setting up Apache on Ubuntu+Django

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, django, memcached, 500-error

I tried with Apache on ubuntu 9.04 and get the same error: Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

And my apache/error.log is:

```
[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] ServerName: 'sapint2'

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] DocumentRoot: '/etc/apache2/htdocs' [Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] URI: '/' 

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] Location: '/' 

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] Directory: None 

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] Filename: '/etc/apache2/htdocs' 

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] PathInfo: '/' 

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] Traceback (most recent call last): 

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch\n default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target\n result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target\n result = object(arg)

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 180, in handler\n return ModPythonHandler()(req)

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 142, in call\n self.load_middleware()

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware\n mod = import_module(mw_module)

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module\n import(name)

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 4, in \n from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 25, in \n from django.core.cache import get_cache

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/init.py", line 187, in \n cache = get_cache(DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS)

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/init.py", line 179, in get_cache\n cache = backend_cls(location, params)

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 139, in init\n "Memcached cache backend requires either the 'memcache' or 'cmemcache' library"

[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] InvalidCacheBackendError: Memcached cache backend requires either the 'memcache' or 'cmemcache' library [Sat Oct 06 09:51:30 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down [Sat Oct 06 09:51:31 2012] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.

[Sat Oct 06 09:51:31 2012] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp

[Sat Oct 06 09:51:31 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.11 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.1+ mod_wsgi/3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I need some help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What Django version you are using? Have you tried acting on the log messages you got and installed one of the suggested memcache libraries? It's right there:

```
[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] File
  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py",
  line 139, in init\n "Memcached cache backend requires either the
 'memcache' or 'cmemcache' library"
[Sat Oct 06 09:32:04 2012] [error] [client 10.0.64.10] InvalidCacheBackendError:
  Memcached cache backend requires either the
 'memcache' or 'cmemcache' library
```

This is the reason your apache returns a 500 error.

Comment: Hi for the tips. Django version is: 1.2.5 and memchached is installed. I troed with install cmemcache library and udo easy_install sqlalchemy and sudo easy_install -U python-memcached.

Comment: Also: sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev tdsodbc. SQLAlchemy==0.7.9 unixODBC 2.2.14 Version: 0.82-7